# Why can't System.Runtime be used in Windows 8.1 packages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, windows-runtime, nuget

I'm using the new "Class Library (NuGet Package)" template in Visual Studio and I need my package to be available for all Windows 8+ and Windows Phone 8.1 apps. However, it blows up when I try to retarget it to those frameworks, and says that types like `object` or `string` are "not defined."

To repro:

1. Create a new "Class Library (Package)" project in Visual Studio.
2. Double-click on **project.json** and change the target framework from `dotnet` to `netcore45` ([table here](http://oren.codes/2015/06/09/pcls-net-core-dnx-and-uwp/) for more info).
3. **BAM!** 14 errors right out of the box. Even if you change `System.Runtime` to `4.0.0` (which is compatible with Windows 8) and get rid of the other dependencies, you still get errors about how `System.Void`, `System.String`, etc. etc. are not defined.

Does anyone know a solution to this problem? I can't just retarget it to Windows 10, because I need to use it in another library that targets those platforms.

**edit:** When I target it to Windows 10 by changing it to `netcore50` it works perfectly, but I can't do that for said reasons.

Comment: You need to pick the class library project type that targets those platforms.

Comment: @Bart and WiredPrairie, .NET Core projects should be portable to other platforms, it works perfectly with Windows 10 for example.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, finally! To fix it, change `dependencies` to `frameworkAssemblies`:

```
{
    // ...

    "frameworks": {
        "netcore45": {
            "frameworkAssemblies": {
                "System.Runtime": ""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks **so much** to [this project](https://github.com/shiftkey/dnx-netcore45-monitor-issue/blob/6514b69336c2dcc0b8d3129fe73baa7b398f6818/src/ExperimentWithLock/project.json#L13-L21), I spent 6 hours looking for the solution. It's very misleading too, because Visual Studio doesn't offer autocomplete when you type `frameworkAssemblies`.